# How can I display 3 records grouped into 1 row in MS-Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want the data in table1 to display as in table in MS access 2000

```
| contact_id | name                           | contact_type | 
| 297        | Primary Properties Corporation | Supplier     |
| 297        | Primary Properties Corporation | Prospect     |
| 297        | Primary Properties Corporation | Customer     |
| 298        | San Miguel Corporation         | Prospect     |
| 301        | Sulpicio Lines                 | Supplier     |
```

I would like it to return:

```
| contact_id | name                           | contact_type    
|  297       | Primary Properties Corporation | Supplier, Prospect, Customer |
|  298       | San Miguel Corporation         | Prospect                     |
|  301       | Sulpicio Lines                 | Supplier                     |
```

I got some ways like using group concat, xml_path in sql, but it doesn't work in ms access.

Please guide me in this.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way:

1. Open the Visual Basic Editor... *Tools --> Macro --> Visual Basic Editor*   (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>)
2. Insert a module and paste in this UDF:

   ```
   'Concat returns a comma-seperated list of items
   Public Function Concat (CategoryCol As String, _
                           ItemCol     As String) As String
       Static LastCategory As String
       Static ItemList     As String

       If CategoryCol      = LastCategory Then
           ItemList        = ItemList & ", " & ItemCol
       Else
           LastCategory    = CategoryCol
           ItemList        = ItemCol
       End If
       Concat = ItemList
   End Function
   ```
3. Save the project and close the VB editor
4. Under *Queries*, Create a new query in design view.
5. Switch to the ***SQL View***.
6. Paste in this SQL:

   ```
   SELECT 
       contact_id,
       name,
       LAST (Concat (contact_id, contact_type))  AS [contact_type]
   FROM
       table1
   GROUP BY
       contact_id,
       name
   ORDER BY
       contact_id
   ```
7. Run the query (Press the red exclamation mark or just select the *Datasheet View*).
8. Done!

Comment: This works quick for small tables.

But the query is taking long time to retrieve data from my table, which has nearly 8000 records. Is there any ways to reduce the time taken?

Comment: You may have to open a new question for that.  Basically, MS access was not meant to do much manipulation with too much data. ... You might be tempted to copy the data to a denormalized column, but that would be a mistake.  The smart thing to do is to port the data to MS SQL server. You can use a basic edition of MS-SQL for free.  You can also link MS Access to tables in MS SQL, using Access as an application front-end.